# How to set Android Material-Design TextInputEditText Leading-Icon?

Tags: android, icons, material-design, android-textinputedittext

[image]How to set the Leading-Icon in TextInputEditText of Material Design for Android? I only found how to set the Leading-Icon.

With drawableLeft the Icon is not centered vertically. Gravity has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. The Container TextInputLayout of TextInputEditText has a attribute called app:startIconDrawable where you can set the leading icon of the textfield. The attribute "drawableLeft" does not work if you use material design.

[image]